# Initializer chaining ('super.init') cannot be nested in another expression

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, initialization

Why do I receive the below error in this code?

```
final class HomeViewController : someBaseClass {    

init(something: SomethingProtocol) {
            someFunction {
                self.something = something
                super.init(nibName: Self.nibName(), bundle: Bundle.main) //here
            }
        }
}
```

**Initializer chaining ('super.init') cannot be nested in another expression**

Comment: The error message is quite clear about what you're doing wrong. And anyway your code is nonsense (I don't actually believe it's your real code).

Comment: I edited to show that HomeViewController inherits from some class, since otherwise it would be pointless to call super.init().

Comment: you're right @matt, I made some changes and accidentally removed the inheritance part. Thanks Christophe for repairing it. matt The error message isn't clear because it doesn't tell the cause. I'm asking about the cause, not the way to to resolve this.

Comment: Don't "make some changes". Code that you show on Stack Overflow should be copied and pasted from real (though possibly minimalized) code from which the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: Sure, thanks @matt, of course the idea was to minimalize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of the [two phase initialization](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID216) principle used by swift:

- first the (designated) initialiser must make sure that every stored property of the class is initialized
- then only it can call the superclass initialiser but still without referring to self in the parameters,
- then it can make whatever it wants, and in particular call instance methods, read the values of instance properties, or refer to self (because at least all the properties of the class hierarchy would be initialized).

In your code,  you're first calling a function using a trailing closure that is supposed to do the necessary steps.  This is not allowed, since the function does not know the state of the initialization and could assume that the object already finished phase 1.  This is why you get this error message.

Moreover the call to `super.init()` refers to self in the parameters, whereas phase 1 of the initialization is not yet finished and it would still be unsafe to refer to self.  So even if you would do things properly before calling the closure, you'd get an error message:

```
init(something: SomethingProtocol) {
    self.something = something
    super.init(nibName: self.nibName(), bundle: Bundle.main) // OUCH!!
    someFunction {
            ...
    }
}
```

The error message would be explicit as well: "*'self' used in method call 'nibName' before 'super.init' call*".  This is because the parameters must be evaluated before the call can be made and breaks again the two phase initialization.